# Firebase facebook authentication is crashing

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, fbsdkloginkit

I have app whose firebase facebook authentication worked just fine... then without any code change it started to crash and i don't get any error message in the output, the only clue i get is an highlited line that tells me nothing about the issue. it's this line:

```
  return ((Implmentation)originalImplementation)(object, selector, application, url,
                                               sourceApplication, annotation);
```

in the FIRAuthAppDelegateProxy.m file and the whole function is this one:

```
    - (BOOL)object:(id)object
             selector:(SEL)selector
          application:(UIApplication *)application
              openURL:(NSURL *)url
    sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
           annotation:(id)annotation {
  if (object == _appDelegate && [self delegateCanHandleURL:url]) {
    return YES;
  }
  IMP originalImplementation = [self originalImplementationForSelector:selector];
  if (originalImplementation && originalImplementation != &noop) {
    typedef BOOL (*Implmentation)(id, SEL, UIApplication*, NSURL *, NSString *, id);
    return ((Implmentation)originalImplementation)(object, selector, application, url,
                                                   sourceApplication, annotation);
  }
  return NO;
}
```

what i've tried so far was to update the pod file and to remove some errors like this one:

> The `APPNAME [Debug]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-APPNAME/Pods-APPNAME.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

But without success.
Can anyopne help me with this, please?

Edit: Here is the FBSDKGraphRequest writen in Swift:

func fetchProfile()
        {

```
        if FBSDKAccessToken.current() == nil
    {
        print("here we are fetching the profile the token was nil")
    let parameters = ["fields": "id, email, first_name, last_name, picture.type(normal)"]
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters).start { (connection, result, error) in

        if error != nil
        {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        print("here paramateres", parameters)
```

Comment: Possibly some of the internal API is deprecated on which the SDK depends, we would need the code to debug to know in detail.
Is the project written in Swift or Objective C?

Comment: @saketkumar the project is writen in Swift i'll edit the question to include the FBSDKGraphRequest

Comment: I also have a lot of warnings In the FBSDKLoginKit but there is no critical one it seems. However, I'll try to silence them to see if somethong change.